# WYSIWYG view bound to Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor to create a simple WYSIWYG editor for a client.

I've seen divshot.com has a WYSIWYG editor that also uses Ace, but I can't figure out how they select elements on the page. They also are able to properly select elements in their code view and it properly selects items in the page view.

setting content in Ace editor is pretty basic

```
editor.setValue('some text content');
```

so how can i make the elements in my wysiwyg view bound to Ace editor?

btw I'm using Angular as well and my WYSIWYG content view is an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It's very, very difficult (I'm a cofounder of Divshot).

We wrote a proprietary component recognition engine that allows for two-way syncing between an ACE Editor instance and a rendered HTML canvas. It involves lots and lots of DOM traversal, selector recognition, source cleaning, and ACE hacking.

Comment: yes i think i might have to skip this feature. Ace is not properly setup to work with dom. Maybe another online code editor would've been a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the session for the editor and grab the current text that way.

```
rte.editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
   var text = rte.editor.getSession().getValue();
   $('#output').html(text);
});
```

Comment: thanks but my problem isn't about getting the text. It's about knowing which line belongs to which dom element in the preview window.